# Force Smart Tags and Accelerators to Appear (or to Disappear) in Microsoft Office Word 2019

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2019, microsoft-word-2019

An issue I have wondered about for years. At times it is mildly iniquitous; at other times it is seriously irritating; and some of the time it is veritably cataclysmic.

Since at least MS Office 2007, whenever one does a certain action (eg paste text in to Word), a little miniature menu usually appears in the vicinity of the action-just-performed as one hovers one's mouse over the location of the, say, just-pasted-in text, which menu says, in this case, "Paste Options".

These little mini-menu's are apparently referred to as "Smart Tags" (somewhat similar to Internet Explorer Accelerators... oh, how we all loved those!) and are not too dissimilar to the mouse right-click-menu's seen in most operating systems.

Now, the issue with these tags is that, in Word'07, they were (relatively) easily removable, as is explained in this rather detailed official MS technical article : https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/description-of-the-smart-tags-in-word-eff0db0e-893a-31eb-a3dd-6998307e098f ...(& scroll down to the "Turn Smart Tags on or off" section)

An equivalent "easy fix" does not seem to be available in Word'19 and no similar ms support article seems to be in existence ; thus hapless users are forced to simply abide by this issue and tolerate the necessity of having to be constantly ESC-ing-off such incidious floating mini-menus each and every time one needs to paste some morsel of text.

On the other end of the spectrum, sometimes your unsuspecting user WANTS to encounter a (not-so)-smart-tag, yet one is prominently nowhere to be found. See this issue :
[Indent an Entire Paragraph in Microsoft Word 2019 with TAB key (instead of indenting a single line)](https://superuser.com/questions/1831343/indent-an-entire-paragraph-in-microsoft-word-2019-with-tab-key-instead-of-inden)
...for a description of a situation in which a "drive-by" smart tag has wreaked havoc, and then gone conspicuously underground, as it were, and is adamantly refusing to show its pretty little face ever again. Hence forcing said unsuspecting user to spend the rest of their now destroyed workday in pulling their hair out and reading forum posts galore and, finally and desperately, registering at SuperUser in the dire hope of solving said unforeseen circumstance.

So the double-question that is the crux of this issue really is this :

(a) how to DIS-able smart tags in Word'16+ (in fact, in Office'16+) ; and, much more importantly :

(b) how to FORCE the Appearance of a smart tag, which HAS appeared in the past but which now REFUSES to appear... yet which contains CRUCIAL options which the user might-or-might-not pressingly require in order to retain their fast-outflowing sanity.

I understand, you understand, that both of these issues might actualy not have a solution. I am braced for this eventuality.

Thank you. And apologies for... you know. Length. And such.

Answer (score 0):

You really gotta make your questions shorter ;)

In summary, you are mixing up a few things.

### Mini Toolbar

Appears when selecting text. Can be (de)activated under "File" > "Options" > "General" > "User Interface Options" > "Show Mini Toolbar on Selection".

[image]

### Paste Options

Appears when you paste something into the document. Can be (de)activated under "File" > "Options" > "Advanced" > "Cut, copy, and paste" > "Show Paste Options Button when content is pasted".

[image]

### AutoCorrect Options

Appears whenever an AutoCorrect is triggered, so that you have the options to reverse this automatic edit or change the behaviour. Can be (de)activated under "File" > "Options" > "Proofing" > "AutoCorrect options" > "AutoCorrect Options..." > "AutoCorrect" tab > "Show AutoCorrect Options button".

[image]

The Mini Toolbar and the Paste Options will always appear if you have them activated. The AutoCorrect Options will only appear if you have it activated **AND** if an AutoCorrect setting is triggered. If no AutoCorrect setting is triggered, then it will of course not show up, because then it would have to show up every single time you click somewhere. Imagine, each time you click somewhere, the Mini Toolbar, the Paste Options and the AutoCorrect options all appear out of nowhere and for no reason. This would be super unproductive.
So, once you deactive an AutoCorrect trigger as you described in your other post, the AutoCorrect option will of course not show up anymore. Because Word didn't automatically correct something for you, so there is no reason to show a button which basically says "do you want to undo this automatic action".